# How to add boostrap to a project that is heavily using Blueprint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big project that heavily embraces BluePrint CSS.

I want to use some components (actually Radio button group) provided by Bootstrap. If I add the CSS/Images/JS given by Bootstrap, wont it conflict with current classes defined by Blueprint.

One option I'm thinking is to conservatively add Bootstrap and use its classes. Is it possible? Can I define a new "namespace" for Bootstrap CSS classes alone in my project and isolate it from classes defined by Blueprint. I can then use classes like `boot-classname` and it would apply styles of `classname` from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the bootstrap radio button code and include it rather than include the entire stylesheet which would override a lot of code you already have.

E.g.  (including checkboxes as well though you could just remove the .checkbox bit)

```
    label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
     }

     .radio,
    .checkbox {
      min-height: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .radio input[type="radio"],
    .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
      float: left;
      margin-left: -20px;
    }

    .controls > .radio:first-child,
    .controls > .checkbox:first-child {
      padding-top: 5px;
    }

    .radio.inline,
    .checkbox.inline {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .radio.inline + .radio.inline,
    .checkbox.inline + .checkbox.inline {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

Also you may want to change the label to a class e.g .boot-label, so it doesn't affect your blueprint label css.